# How to send to front/back ("z-order") when editing an image in Preview

Tags: macos, preview

I have added an oval to an image in `Preview` and would like to either send it to back or change its transparency:

[image]

Well maybe the `transparency` were asking too much of `Preview`  - but the others?

[image]

Why are they disabled?  Is there a way to get the oval to not blot out the area it covers?

**Update**: Attempt to set transparency:

[image]

Note: the `oval` has become `completely invisible` now: the blue dots show the location of the timid object:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it transparent, open the color picker on the very right, and chose the white square with the red line through it.

[image]

The other options are disabled because there is no object underneath/above it to send behind/in front of. The image itself you are editing does not count as an object.

Comment: Did the opposite of what i had hoped for: it made the _entire oval_ disappear  but still obscuring the underling image ;)  Is there a chance the transparency color needs to be adjusted?

Comment: Updated the question: it is the top left with red line diagonal as you showed. It *is* transparent the second time I tried: but it is more than that - it is _entirely_ inivislble now - it has no effect: that is shown in the second image just added where the blue dots are.

Comment: @javadba That is because the first color picker to the left of it is also white with a red line through it. Change the first color picker to a different color and it should be visible again.